# CSS Parallax background on scroll with CSS and without javascript

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a parallax scrolling background that uses CSS only ([plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ye91S1OelMbGfCUsj4Sf?p=preview)) but I can't figure out a way to keep the background content strictly within the red boxes.

In short, I'm looking to achieve a similar effect as the scrolling background images as [this one](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-gb/). Note that there are multiple pictures which are framed within each segment that scroll more slowly to emulate a 3D depth effect.

Now I know this is possible with JavaScript of course, but after pondering whether this could simply be achieved with some trick of of coordinate systems I found [this](http://codepen.io/keithclark/details/JycFw) example. Unfortunately the author didn't explain his work but the basic technique is to use `transform: translateZ()` to achieve the depth without the emulation hack and then playing tricks with the coordinate system of scrolling sections.

Here's the code from the plunkr;

```html
<body>

<div class="slideWrapper">
<div id="slide1Img" class="slideImg"></div>
<div id="slide1" class="slide">
  start is some text... end
  <div class="footer">
    footer text - picture should be based above this line
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="slideWrapper">
  <div id="slide2Img" class="slideImg"></div>
  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    start2 is some different text ...some end2
    <div class="footer">
      footer text - picture should be based above this line
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

with

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden; /* hide the normal page scrollbar */
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* this replaces the usual scrollbar we turned off but with 3d transforms */

    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: top;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.slideWrapper {
    position: relative; /* coord stop */
}

.slide {
    font-size: 200%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#slide1Img {
  background-image: url("http://www.kennethprimrose.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Scottish-landscape..jpg");
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2) translateY(0%);
}
#slide2Img {
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSadcIZ_y-14V-Z5Q-nm843xz69GLr5glv19DZcjTQKjBcd7QC0");
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2) translateY(50%); /* hack */
}

.slideImg {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    z-index: -1;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

There are two 'sections' defined by the red boxes, each with a footer. The images are supposed to move slowly on scroll *within* the red boxes but that's the closest I was able to get today.

I'm posting this question here in the hope that collectively the community may be able to take this solution further...

Comment: [This site here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) was previously posted as an answer and should have been a comment. Could be useful!